# Algorithm to convert any real number into a continued fraction

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

I'm looking for an algorithm that wolframalpha  uses to convert any real number into a continued fraction. See the following examples:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Continued+fraction+199111377%2F60034339
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued+fraction+sqrt(11)

What I've been trying so far is a function written in PHP (apologies for the variable naming and formatting) that converts any rational value  into a Continued fraction. However, if I pass an irrational value into the function it returns the result for the nearest rational.

Here is the function code:

```
function solve($g) {
    for ($i = 1; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
        if (abs($i * $g - round($i * $g)) < 0.000001) {
            $numerator = round($g * $i);
            $denominator = $i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($numerator > $denominator) {
        $ratio = (int)($numerator / $denominator);
        $mod = $numerator % $denominator;
        $numerator = $denominator;
        $denominator = $mod;
        echo ('[' . $ratio . ';');
        $s = 1;
    } else {
        $c = $numerator;
        $numerator = $denominator;
        $denominator = $c;
        $ratio = (int)($numerator / $denominator);
        $mod = $numerator % $denominator;
        $numerator = $denominator;
        $denominator = $mod;
        echo ('[0;' . $ratio . ',');
        $s = 2;
    }

    while ($numerator % $denominator > 0) {
        $ratio = (int)($numerator / $denominator);
        $mod = $numerator % $denominator;
        $numerator = $denominator;
        $denominator = $mod;
        $s++;
        echo ($ratio . ',');
    }

    echo ($numerator / $denominator);
    echo (']');
}
```

The function is called as `solve(sqrt(11));`

Comment: Without looking at the code itself, here are two comments: $\;\;\;$(1) I think PHP uses floating-point representation for "real numbers", so the input to this routine will always be a rational number. (If you pass, for example, $\operatorname{sqrt}(11),$ you'll be passing whatever PHP returns for $\operatorname{sqrt}(11),$ which is some rational approximation to $\sqrt{11}.\;\;\;$ (2) If you did switch to some representation that allowed some irrational numbers to be represented, there still is no nearest rational to any irrational number. For any rational approximation, there's a closer one.

Comment: The algorithm can become problematic even if a powerful program is used because the continued fraction might contain very, very large entries. PARI/GP is already powerful enough to calculate continued fractions with many entries if they are not too large. A period only occurs for real numbers with a minimal polynomial of degree $2$, in other words, numbers of the form $a+b\cdot \sqrt{c}$, where $a$ and $b$ are rationals and $c$ is a positive integer not being a square. The continued fraction of other irrational numbers can only be calculated completely in special cases (for example $e$)